# Como carregar arquivo .JS dependendo da largura da tela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, layout-responsivo

Eu tenho um arquivo `.js` que gostaria de carregar apenas para versão Desktop, quando for em telas mais estreites gostaria que a requisição para esse `.js` não fosse feita, ou até mesmo fosse carregado outro `.js`. Tipo, para *telas grandes > 768px* carrega `desktop.js`, e *para telas < que 786px* carrega `mobile.js`

Sei que para CSS pode ser feito assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css"  media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" />
```

E para imagens podemos fazer assim por exemplo:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="desktop.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset="mobile.jpg"  media="(max-width: 767px)">
  <img srcset="mobile.jpg" alt="…">
</picture>
```

***Então ficou a dúvida, tem como fazer algo parecido para requisições de arquivos `.js` dependendo do width da tela?***

Comment: Cara eu testei e funcionou! Mas se for com o simulador do Chrome DevTools não da certo, pra ver funcionando tem que diminuir na mão a janela do Browser. Valeu a dica!